# How does this algebraic trick work?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Consider

$$ \left(\dfrac{2bc}{2c}\right)^2 - \left(\dfrac{-a^2+b^2+c^2}{2c}\right)^2 \quad.$$

They rewrite this as: $$ \dfrac{(2bc-a^2+b^2+c^2)(2bc+a^2-b^2-c^2)}{4c^2} \quad .$$

I don't understand this trick, and I want to know the logic behind it; why $(-a^2+b^2+c^2)$ added to $2bc$ in the first one and subtracted from $2bc$ in the second one, for example.

Comment: hint :  difference of squares

Comment: Hint: You do know that $a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)$, yes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT : $$A^2-B^2=(A+B)(A-B).$$

Comment: Oh, darn. I wasn't smart enough to rewrite it to that form in my head. Thanks.

Comment: @Phaptitude: You are welcome.

Comment: @Phaptitude: any time I see a difference of squares, this identity comes to mind. It is very useful.